# Compare two dates in vb.net whether they are equal or not

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, date-comparison

I have a **Date** variable `startdt` and a **String** variable `hdnsdate`.

Suppose if `startdt` has the value in the form **3/1/2012** and `hdnsdate` has the value in the form **03/01/2012**. Than how can i compare that these two dates are equal in **vb.net**.

In `if` condition of my program i want to do this check. In case the two dates match move out of `if` loop otherwise go into the `if` loop.

E.g A sample in C# what exactly i want.

```
if(startdt !=hdnsdate)
{
 //Do
}
else
{
//Do this
}
```

Comment: Your code example is C#, but you tagged this with VB.NET - which is it?

Comment: @Oded C# is a sample, i want to do that in vb.net

Comment: Your code samples should really reflect the tag. This is just confusing.

Comment: @Oded Thank You, il keep taht in ind next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse  `hdnsdate` (string) to Date type using Parse, ParseExact method and use [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx), `Equals`, `CompareTo` methods.

String to date

```
 Dim enddate as Date
 Date.TryParse(hdnsdate, enddate)

 If startdt = enddate Then
   'Do this
 Else
   'Do this
 End If
```

Alternative to compare date:

```
Dim result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2)
If result=0 Then
  'Do this
End If
```

Comment: result = 0 if they are equal ?

Comment: @Web.11 Yes! It returns greater than zero when date1 is later than date2, returns less than zero when date1 is earlier than date2 and returns 0 when date1 is same as date2.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse the string into a `DateTime` then compare the two.

VB.NET

```
Dim parsed As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(hdnsdate)

If startdt != parsed Then

Else

End If
```

C#:

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(hdnsdate);

if(startdt != parsed )
{
 //Do
}
else
{
//Do this
}
```

I suggest looking at the different parsing methods defined on `DateTime`, as you may need to use a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date and time format string to ensure the string gets parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim result = DateTime.Compare(hdnsdate, date2)
If result=0 Then
  'Do this
End If
```

Comment: you can refer this link also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx